# Unable to change HTML iframe source with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to have a 'video of the day' on my website. I currently have most of this working, and here's how I plan to have it working in the end:

- Have a Python script run once every 24 hours to pick the random YouTube video of the day
- Write the embedded video URL to a text file
- Use Javascript to access the text file and grab the video URL, and use it as the iframe source on my webpage

As I mentioned above, this plan is currently working for the most part. My script is able to pick the random video, and write it to a text file. My web page is then able to pull the video URL from the text file, and write it to the webpage in text form. However, I'm having some troubles having it write the video URL to my iframe.

I did some searching, and people suggested trying the following code:

```
<iframe id="mainvideo" width="720" height="480" frameborder="0" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById("mainvideo").src =
          finalresult + ReturnURL();
</script>
```

So earlier in my code, I declared the variable 'finalresult' to be the following value: `//www.youtube.com/embed/WJDnJ0vXUgw`

When I have Javascript write 'finalresult' to my webpage, it will write the video URL as text to the webpage as expected. However, when I try and declare it as the source for the iframe, I end up with a blank iframe on the page.

Does anyone know what the problem is with my code for it not showing this video in my iframe? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try document.getElementById("mainvideo").setAttribute("src",fullPath);

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with your URL. This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wbskapcc/

Comment: Does ist work if you specify `src="//www.youtube.com/embed/WJDnJ0vXUgw"` directly in your code? The `//www` part looks a bit strange.

Comment: If finalresult has what you need then why to add ReturnUrl()?

Comment: @Ridcully Yes, it works with the //www part. It indeed does look a little weird. I'm not sure why I had it like that, because it looks like when YouTube provides you with code to embed a video in a pagepage, it begins with `https://www.`.

Comment: @SerifEmek I modified my code and found I didn't need it so I removed it. Originally when I posted this topic I was just following another thread I found online, and they used ReturnUrl() in their example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be changing the `src` after any particular `event` is fired. So try this way,

***HTML :***

```
<iframe id="mainvideo" width="720" height="480" frameborder="0" src="http://www.bing.com/" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<button id="changeSrc">Change iFrame</button>
```

***javaScript :***

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("mainvideo");

changeSrc.onclick = function(){
    iframe.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
};
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/v1q07beb/)

***Update 1 :***

If you want to change the iframe `src` attribute after page load then go with this way,

```
window.onload = function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("mainvideo");
    iframe.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
};
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/rwedd6aL/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I would like to implement something like this, but without the button. Do you know if there's a way I can have it change the iframe src after it loads a certain image or something like that? I was thinking I could use onload, but I'm not sure if that would work out.

Answer (score 0):

If `myframe.src` does not work for you, then try out `myframe.contentWindow.location.href` like [in this pen](https://codepen.io/paperluigis/pen/VwjoPxa).